# Want to create a 2D pointer storing Nx3 values in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, output

I have written the code below and I wish to use it to store some values using an if-else condition. For storing the values, I have create two 2-D pointers, *p and *q. Now the code seems to run okay, but I am unable to print out the values stored in the pointers p and q. Could you please help me out here? What am I doing wrong"?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i, j, N;
    double xtmp, ytmp, ztmp, delx, dely, delz, fpair, cutsq;
    double rsq, r2inv, r6inv, forcelj; 
    double firstval[2][3], secondval[2][3];
    double (*p)[2][3] = 0; 
    double (*q)[2][3] = 0;
    int f[2][3];
    p =& firstval;
    q =& secondval;

    double x[2][3] =
    {
        {0.1,0.8,0.12},
        {0.5,0.9,0.13}
    };

    N = 2;
    cutsq = 1.0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            xtmp = x[i][0];
            ytmp = x[i][1];
            ztmp = x[i][2]; 

            delx = xtmp - x[j][0];
            dely = ytmp - x[j][1];
            delz = ztmp - x[j][2];
            rsq = delx * delx + dely * dely + delz * delz;
            if (rsq < cutsq) 
            {
                r2inv = 1.0 / rsq;
                r6inv = r2inv * r2inv * r2inv;
                forcelj = r6inv * 1;
                fpair = forcelj * r2inv;

                f[i][0] += delx * fpair;
                f[i][1] += dely * fpair;
                f[i][2] += delz * fpair;
                f[j][0] -= delx * fpair;
                f[j][1] -= dely * fpair;
                f[j][2] -= delz * fpair;

                if (i != j)
                {
                    (*p)[i][0] += delx * fpair;
                    (*p)[i][1] += dely * fpair;
                    (*p)[i][2] += delz * fpair;
                    (*p)[j][0] -= delx * fpair;
                    (*p)[j][1] -= dely * fpair;
                    (*p)[j][2] -= delz * fpair;
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                     (*q)[i][0] += delx * fpair;
                     (*q)[i][1] += dely * fpair;
                     (*q)[i][2] += delz * fpair;
                     (*q)[j][0] -= delx * fpair;
                     (*q)[j][1] -= dely * fpair;
                     (*q)[j][2] -= delz * fpair;
                 }

                 std::cout << firstval << "\n";
            }
        }
    }         
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly before you post your question.

Comment: Furthermore what output are you actually getting at the moment?

Comment: Could not replicate: https://ideone.com/ElFZxo

Comment: `std::cout<<firstval<<"\n";` - There's no method that knows how to print a 2x3 matrix of doubles.  You'll need to iterate across the rows/columns to print each element manually.

Answer (score 1):

I have no doubt that there's a smarter way, but...
you could write
a) a template that "knows" how to stream a double[N] and
b) a template that knows (based on the first one) how to stream a double[M][N]

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &o, const T(&a)[N]) {
    o << '[' << a[0];  // iirc zero-sized arrays are not allowed ....better look it up though.
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
        o << ',' << a[i];
    }
    o << ']';
    return o;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &o, const T(&a)[M][N]) {
    o << '{' << a[0];
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < M; ++i) {
        o << ',' << a[i];
    }
    o << '}';
    return o;
}
```

and *then* you can do `std::cout << firstval << std::endl;`

---

edit: And of course there's a more generic solution

```
template <typename T> void print_array(const T & a, std::size_t level=0);
template <typename T>
void print_array_impl(const T & a, std::size_t level, std::true_type)
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (auto & x : a) print_array(x, level+1);
    fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), level, ' ');
}

template <typename T>
void print_array_impl(const T & a, std::size_t level, std::false_type)
{
    for (auto & x : a) std::cout << x << ',';
}

template <typename T>
void print_array(const T & a, std::size_t level)
{
    fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), level, ' ');
    std::cout << '[';
    print_array_impl(a, level, std::is_array<typename std::remove_extent<T>::type>());
    std::cout << ']' << std::endl;
```

}

.oO( I need to brush up my c++; that still doesn't look elegant.... )